# How split date in this line?

Tags: java, string, parsing, split, simpledateformat

I have some problem with parse some information from String line. In this example, I would like to work with the line `2011-08-28 19:02:30`.
I have a lot of lines for this template. How to parse this date? Thanks

```
 [47.611910999999999, -122.335178]  6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 I'm at Saigon Vietnamese Restaurant II (1529 6th Ave., at Pine St., Seattle) http://example.com
```

Thanks all. Here is my solution.

```
 private Date parseDate(String line) {
    line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
    String[] masWords = line.split(" ");
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
   try {
        date = format.parse(masWords[3] + " " + masWords[4]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: @sferencik in my example it is necessary to cut a string date

Comment: @ЕгорУрбанович search for String split.

Answer (score 3):

i'd do it like that:

```
   String[] s1 = "[47.611910999999999, -122.335178]  6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 I'm at Saigon Vietnamese Restaurant II (1529 6th Ave., at Pine St., Seattle) http://t.co/8s86hNX".split(" ");
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        for(int i = 1; i< s1.length ; i++  ){
            try {
                Date date = format.parse(s1[i-1]+" "+s1[i]);
                System.out.println("Date found: "+s1[i-1]+" "+s1[i]);
                break;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

1. Split the String
2. loop through the String Array
3. cast to date until you found a valid date.

if the you know the date is always on the same place in the string you can do it much easier by you cast:

```
String[] s1 = "[47.611910999999999, -122.335178]  6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 I'm at Saigon Vietnamese Restaurant II (1529 6th Ave., at Pine St., Seattle) http://t.co/8s86hNX".split(" ");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.parse(s1[6]+" "+s1[7]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to normalize your string by **removing the extra spaces**... () Regex can do that fast and easy), then **split the string**, **concatenate the elements of the string that you need for building a date**, **parse** those to a Date object Woala...

a snippet for this:

```
String chain = "[47.611910999999999, -122.335178]  6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 I'm at Saigon Vietnamese Restaurant II (1529 6th Ave., at Pine St., Seattle) http://t.co/8s86hNX";
        chain = chain.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
        System.out.println(chain);
        String[] var = chain.split(" ");
        for (String string : var) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

        String string = var[3] + " " + var[4];
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = format.parse(string);
        System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Good Example. Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

1. Split with a space as the delimiter `String[] parts = str.split(" ");`
2. Loop through `parts[]` to find items matching your date and time.
3. You can use the following regexes:

   - Date: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`
   - Time: `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`
4. You can work with detected strings containing your time and date using `java.util.Date`